# IDirect3D8->CreateDevice() only works if I click into, out, then into again a window. EnumWindows problem?

Tags: c++, windows, directx, hook

So I'm hooking the EndScene function in a game to create a UI for my mod to it. And everything works fine when I click into, out, then into again the window I'm injecting my dll into. I'm using EnumWindows which is probably the problem, but I can't figure out what excatly.

When the CreateDevice failes I have a handle too, but I'm guessing it's a wrong one that's why it failes. I checked when it fails the window is not minimzed with `IsIconic()`.

Any idea?

```
BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsCallback(HWND handle, LPARAM lParam)
{
    DWORD wndProcId;

    GetWindowThreadProcessId(handle, &wndProcId);

    DWORD processId = GetCurrentProcessId();

    if (processId != wndProcId)
        return TRUE;

    IGui::window = handle;

    return FALSE;
}

HWND DXHook::GetProcessWindow()
{
    IGui::window = NULL;

    EnumWindows(EnumWindowsCallback, NULL);

    return IGui::window;
}

void DXHook::EndSceneHook()
{
    IDirect3D8* pD3D = Direct3DCreate8(D3D_SDK_VERSION);

    if (!pD3D)
    {
        return;
    }

    IDirect3DDevice8* pDevice = nullptr;

    D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS d3dparams = {};
    d3dparams.Windowed = true;
    d3dparams.SwapEffect = D3DSWAPEFFECT_DISCARD;
    d3dparams.hDeviceWindow = GetProcessWindow();

    HRESULT result = pD3D->CreateDevice(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT, D3DDEVTYPE_HAL, d3dparams.hDeviceWindow, D3DCREATE_HARDWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING, &d3dparams, &pDevice);

    if (result != S_OK)
    {
        d3dparams.Windowed = !d3dparams.Windowed;

        result = pD3D->CreateDevice(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT, D3DDEVTYPE_HAL, d3dparams.hDeviceWindow, D3DCREATE_SOFTWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING, &d3dparams, &pDevice);

        if (FAILED(result) || !pDevice)
        {
            pD3D->Release();
            return;
        }
    }

    void** vTable = *reinterpret_cast<void***>(pDevice);

    EndScene = (_endScene)DetourFunction((PBYTE)vTable[35], (PBYTE)HookedEndScene);
    IGui::oWndProc = (WNDPROC)SetWindowLongPtr(IGui::window, GWL_WNDPROC, (LONG_PTR)IGui::WndProc);

    pDevice->Release();
    pD3D->Release();
}
```

I've also tried to hook it in minimized state and it's not working. So I'm pretty sure it's because of the EnumWindows function.

Edit: I'm getting this handle 0x007e07ea or 8259562 in decimal when I should be getting 17384.